# ¿Como crear una nueva columna, en relacion a los valores de otra columna?

Tags: r

Mi objetivo es agrupar los meses del año "month" en una columna independiente, "Step", para cada observación tal que:

- Month = 1 , 2 , 3 correspondan al valor de la columna nueva "Step" = 1
- Month = 4 , 5 , 6 correspondan al valor de la columna nueva "Step" = 2
- Month = 7 , 8 , 9 correspondan al valor de la columna nueva "Step" = 3
- Month = 10 , 11 , 12 correspondan al valor de la columna nueva "Step" = 4

Sin embargo, intentando usar ifelse o mutate no logro conseguirlo.
Esta es la estructura de mi data frame:

```
> str(l0)
'data.frame':   63619 obs. of  27 variables:
 $ Species      : chr  "GHL" "GHL" "GHL" "GHL" ...
 $ SampleNo     : int  150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 ...
 $ Year         : int  2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 ...
 $ year1        : chr  "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" ...
 $ month        : chr  "11" "11" "11" "11" ...
 $ hours        : chr  "05T03" "05T03" "05T03" "05T03" ...
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usualmente para este tipo de ejercicios uso la función case_when(), para el ejemplo seria algo como lo siguiente:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

l0 <- l0 %>%
   mutate(Step = case_when(Month %in% c(1,2,3) ~ 1,
                           Month %in% c(4,5,6) ~ 2,
                           Month %in% c(7,8,9) ~ 3,
                           TRUE ~ 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Con R base puedes anidar varios `ifelse()`

```
l0$Month <- as.numeric(l0$Month)
l0$Step <- ifelse(l0$Month %in% c(1,2,3), 
                  1,
                  ifelse(l0$Month %in% (4,5,6),
                         2,
                         ifelse(l0$Month %in% (7,8,9),
                                3,
                                4)
                  )
)
```

Primero que nada, convertimos la columna en un numérico ya que es un `character`, y debiéramos verificar las existencia de `NA's` por las dudas, luego simplemente anidamos, varios `ifelse()` para tratar cada rango.

Existe otra forma incluso más compacta:

```
cut(l0$Month, 
    breaks=c(-Inf, 3, 6, 9, Inf), 
    labels(c(1, 2, 3, 4))
    )
```

Con `cut()` puedes establecer los puntos de corte de cada rango y la etiqueta que quieres para cada uno de estos. (Recuerda que `Month`  debe ser numérico)